# Якорь картинкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать якорь на центральную часть страницы. Причем якорь должен быть реализован картинкой, при нажатии на которую тебя кидает вниз. Не очень понимаю, как центрировать внутри текст, чтобы при этом сохранить адаптивность.

Comment: Где вам нужно отцентрировать текст и как? (вертикально / горизонтально)

Answer (score 1):

Покажите код, или ссылку на проект.И причем тут текст? если я верно понял вам нужно при клике на картинку переходить в конкретное место.
По идее примерно так

```
<a href="test.php#якорь"><img src=""></a>
```

Если есть текст который нужно центровать то

```
<a style="text-align: center;" href="test.php#якорь"><img src=""></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Кнопка с картинкой

```
  <a href="#anchor">
     <img src="#" alt="#">  
  </a>
```

При нажатии на которую идет переход на блок

```
  <a name="anchor">

  </a>
```